# Creating new Task is not running the entire method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, task, task-parallel-library

I have a calculation that does I/O I want to send to another thread so on the web site the user can goto the next page without waiting for the calculation to finish. From what I understand are I need to do is call the method like this

var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() =>  CalculateSet(uow, profile, userId, specialtyCode ));

But when I do this is seems to call one line in the method and goes away.. non of the work is done.

Am I missing something ?

```
  [Fact]
    public void Calculation_Xls()
    {
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string filesDirectory = currentDirectory + "\\Files";
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RetContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        int i = 0; //outer loop

        UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new RetContext(optionsBuilder.Options));

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filesDirectory + "\\t2UserProfileDataTwoUserPerSpecialty.xlsx",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                do
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (i != 0)
                        {
                            var userId = reader.GetString(0);
                            var specialtyCode = reader.GetString(1);
                            var userProfileElement1_WorkExp = reader.GetValue(2);
                            var userProfileElement2_VolExp = reader.GetValue(3);
                            var userProfileElement3_ResExp = reader.GetValue(4);
                            var userProfileElement4_Pubs = reader.GetValue(5);
                            var userProfileElement5_AOA = reader.GetValue(6);
                            var userProfileElement6_Nspecialties = reader.GetValue(7);
                            var userProfileElement7_PercentApps = reader.GetValue(8);

                            //Create profile
                            UserProfileData profile = new UserProfileData();
                            profile.UserProfileElement1_WorkExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement1_WorkExp);
                            profile.UserProfileElement2_VolExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement2_VolExp);
                            profile.UserProfileElement3_ResExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement3_ResExp);
                            profile.UserProfileElement4_Pubs = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement4_Pubs);
                            profile.UserProfileElement5_Aoa = Convert.ToBoolean(userProfileElement5_AOA);
                            profile.UserProfileElement6_Nspecialties = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement6_Nspecialties);
                            profile.UserProfileElement7_PercentApps = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement7_PercentApps);

                            //Calculate for set of programs. Selects one row at a time from XLS. BulkInsert into DB

                            //THIS ONLY RUNS ONE LINE OF THE METHOD
                             var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() =>  CalculateSet(uow, profile, userId, specialtyCode ));

                            //THIS WORKS
                            //CalculateSet(uow, profile, userId, specialtyCode);
                        }

                        i++;

                        Debug.WriteLine("Bulkcreate complete " + i);


                        //only process xxx rows
                        if (i > 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } while (reader.NextResult());
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Should get here quickly and not wait until task is done");
    }

    private void CalculateSet(UnitOfWork uow, UserProfileData profile, string userId, string specialtyCode)
    {
        //I CAN HIT THIS BREAKPOINT!
        //get specialtyId from code
        var specialtyId = uow.RefMedicalSpecialtyRepository
             .Find(x => x.Code == specialtyCode).FirstOrDefault().Id;

        //NEVER GET TO THIS BREAKPOINT
        //loop through all programs for speciality
        var programsForSpecialty = uow.RefProgramDetailDataRepository
            .Find(x => x.RefMedicalSpecialtyId == specialtyId);

        //List for bulk insert
       // List<UserProgram> userPrograms = new List<UserProgram>();

        //Write a row for each program
        foreach (RefProgramDetailData rpdd in programsForSpecialty.ToList())
        {
            //Get program info
            var programProfile = LoadData.Load_RefProgramProfileData(rpdd.Code);

            //Calculate results
            var userProgram = _calculator.CalculateAll(programProfile, profile, specialtyId, userId);

            //If the Program can not be found in program detail then skip insert
            if (userProgram == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Program NULL");
            }
            else
            {
                //Write results to UserProgram
                 uow.UserProgramRepository.Create(userProgram);

                //userPrograms.Add(userProgram);

                Debug.WriteLine("Program " + programProfile.ProgramCode);
            }
        }

        //bulk insert
       // uow.UserProgramRepository.BulkCreate(userPrograms);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: I put this in my controller. But it is waiting for the Task to finish before it redirects. Why isn't it redirecting immediately ?

```
 await Task.Run(() => _calculator.CalculateAllSet(_unitOfWork, userProfileData, msId, null));



            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: If you're not going to wait for `backgroundTask` to complete, it will just get destroyed when the variable goes out of scope...

Comment: @DavidG No, that's not true.  Tasks are held in scope by the TPL even if you aren't holding onto a reference to them, at least until they finish.

Comment: I would hope that as the user navigates to another page the task is running till completion. Or is the user moving to another MVC controller destroy the task? I am very beginner with this topic.

Comment: @Servy Hmm interesting, I did not know that. Either way, I doubt this is recommended in ASP.Net Core, better to use a tool designed for this like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) or `IHostedService` if we're in Core2?

Comment: Yes. It is asp.net core 2. I will look at those two topics.

Comment: Also worth noting that it looks like this is a unit test method, that means that when your test method exits, it will kill all references to the task and anything else that is running.

Comment: I am moving the code into a controller and using async/await and see if that goes to another page while finishing the process.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like that.

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Calculation_Xls()
        {
            string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string filesDirectory = currentDirectory + "\\Files";
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RetContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            int i = 0; //outer loop

            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new RetContext(optionsBuilder.Options));

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filesDirectory + "\\t2UserProfileDataTwoUserPerSpecialty.xlsx",
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (i != 0)
                            {
                                var userId = reader.GetString(0);
                                var specialtyCode = reader.GetString(1);
                                var userProfileElement1_WorkExp = reader.GetValue(2);
                                var userProfileElement2_VolExp = reader.GetValue(3);
                                var userProfileElement3_ResExp = reader.GetValue(4);
                                var userProfileElement4_Pubs = reader.GetValue(5);
                                var userProfileElement5_AOA = reader.GetValue(6);
                                var userProfileElement6_Nspecialties = reader.GetValue(7);
                                var userProfileElement7_PercentApps = reader.GetValue(8);

                                //Create profile
                                UserProfileData profile = new UserProfileData();
                                profile.UserProfileElement1_WorkExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement1_WorkExp);
                                profile.UserProfileElement2_VolExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement2_VolExp);
                                profile.UserProfileElement3_ResExp = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement3_ResExp);
                                profile.UserProfileElement4_Pubs = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement4_Pubs);
                                profile.UserProfileElement5_Aoa = Convert.ToBoolean(userProfileElement5_AOA);
                                profile.UserProfileElement6_Nspecialties = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement6_Nspecialties);
                                profile.UserProfileElement7_PercentApps = Convert.ToInt32(userProfileElement7_PercentApps);

                                //Calculate for set of programs. Selects one row at a time from XLS. BulkInsert into DB

                                //THIS ONLY RUNS ONE LINE OF THE METHOD
                                 var backgroundTask = await Task.Run(() =>  CalculateSet(uow, profile, userId, specialtyCode ));

                                //THIS WORKS
                                //CalculateSet(uow, profile, userId, specialtyCode);
                            }

                            i++;

                            Debug.WriteLine("Bulkcreate complete " + i);


                            //only process xxx rows
                            if (i > 1)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (reader.NextResult());
                }
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Should get here quickly and not wait until task is done");
        }

        private void CalculateSet(UnitOfWork uow, UserProfileData profile, string userId, string specialtyCode)
        {
            //I CAN HIT THIS BREAKPOINT!
            //get specialtyId from code
            var specialtyId = uow.RefMedicalSpecialtyRepository
                 .Find(x => x.Code == specialtyCode).FirstOrDefault().Id;

            //NEVER GET TO THIS BREAKPOINT
            //loop through all programs for speciality
            var programsForSpecialty = uow.RefProgramDetailDataRepository
                .Find(x => x.RefMedicalSpecialtyId == specialtyId);

            //List for bulk insert
           // List<UserProgram> userPrograms = new List<UserProgram>();

            //Write a row for each program
            foreach (RefProgramDetailData rpdd in programsForSpecialty.ToList())
            {
                //Get program info
                var programProfile = LoadData.Load_RefProgramProfileData(rpdd.Code);

                //Calculate results
                var userProgram = _calculator.CalculateAll(programProfile, profile, specialtyId, userId);

                //If the Program can not be found in program detail then skip insert
                if (userProgram == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Program NULL");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Write results to UserProgram
                     uow.UserProgramRepository.Create(userProgram);

                    //userPrograms.Add(userProgram);

                    Debug.WriteLine("Program " + programProfile.ProgramCode);
                }
            }

            //bulk insert
           // uow.UserProgramRepository.BulkCreate(userPrograms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What parts did you change? just added the async and await ?

Comment: Yes, I added `async` in method, and `await` on `Task.Run`.

Comment: See above EDIT 1. It is waiting until it is done processing. And then it does the redirect :(

Comment: I think you need to do this calculation in another process, I suggest you a HangFire like said previously or a Service.